# Creating a minimum heap of a mapping between an object and a value

Tags: java, object, comparator, heap, minimum

The questions is in Java.

I have some sort of an Object, lets call it `MyObj`. Additionally, I have a way to score each instance of this object. However, the scoring depends also on another integer value. So, I use `Table<MyObj,Integer,Double> valuesOf` to store the values. I'd like to emphasize that I begin with a single value inserted in `valuesOf`, and the rest is being filled on the fly.

While filling these values, I'd like to start each time with the currently best known minimal value. When I say minimal value, I mean that over all possible instances of `MyObj x` and all possible integers `i`, I'm looking at the smallest value of `valuesOf.get(x,i)` that exists in `valuesOf` (so at first, it will be this initial value I'm putting in, and later, well, depends on the values calculated).

So the easiest way is to implement a minimum heap. To do so, I created: `PriorityQueue<Double> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>()`. Then, each time a new value `currNewVal` has been calculated, I added `valuesOf.put(x,i,currNewVal)` and `minHeap.add(currNewVal)`. Each time I want to know the current lowest value, I perform: `Double currValue = minHeap.remove()`.

This works fine for the first iteration. The problem is, I keep knowledge only of the minimal value, and not of the `x` and `i` that resulted in this minimal value. That is, I somehow want to keep the minimal heap aware that, while I am sorting by the value of the double, I am also interested in keeping a pointer to these `x` and `i` that brought me to this value.

I read a bit about implementing comparators. And that means, that I want to create some sort of an object, lets say a combination of `MyObj` and an `int`, and then to implement a comparator for them? But this comparator will be depending on the value from the table `valuesOf`.

I'm not sure this is the right way to go for it. And if it is, I got a bit confused and not sure how exactly to do so. But perhaps there are better ways?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly what you're trying to do: You basically have mapping like `MyObj -> Integer Value -> Double Value`, i.e. `Integer Value` is a secondary key. Now you want to maintain the minimum of `Double Value` per `MyObj`? In that case why don't you just keep a `Map<MyObj, Double>` and when inserting a new value into `valuesOf` you update the value in the "minimum" map if: a) there is no value or b) the current value is not the minimum anymore? You can even make it a `Map<MyObj, MyValue>` where `MyValue` contains `MyObj` as well as the integer key and double value.

Comment: I think you partly got what I meant, so I'll try to clarify. The `Double value` depends on both `MyObj x` and on `int i`. So the dependency is `MyObj X int -> Double`, therefor I used `Table<MyObj,Integer,Double>` to store the values. 
As for your second point, I could always maintain a pointer to the `MyObj x` and `int i` that gave me the current minimal value. But once I extract the minimal value from the heap, these pointers should be changed, and this is the main focus on my question.
Shortly: how do I maintain a min-heap with pointers to `MyObj` and `int` for each value in the heap?

Comment: Ok, so you need to keep all the `x/i` combinations along with their values, right? Just one more clarification: did I understand correctly that the minimum is a global one? Or does it still depend on `x´, i.e. do you need the minimum for a specific `x` object?

Comment: Yes. Ofcourse, it is possible some combinations of `x` and `i` yield no value, I only store the existing values in the `Table<MyVal,Integer,Double> valuesOf` as I do the calculations (and until some boolean condition holds and then I stop filling the table).
The minimum is among all possible pairs `<x,i>` where `x` is of the type `MyObj` and `i` is an integer. 
That is, if I had: `valuesOf(x,1) = 3`, `valuesOf(x,2) = 0.125`, `valuesOf(y,1) = 2.8`, `valuesOf(z,1) = 1.705` and `valuesOf(z,2) = 0.001` Then at first the minimal value is `0.001` and then its `0.125` and then `1.705` and so on.

Comment: One more comment, it is possible that I extracted the minimal value of, lets say, `0.001` from the above example. What I am missing is to extract both `z` and `2`. But lets say I somehow found them. So I am calculating new values. So now I may add to the table the value `valuesOf(w,1) = 0.1` (for example), so the next minimal one is `0.1` from `(w,1)`. That's why I was leaning towards a minimum heap, because I can simply use `add` and it rebalances itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the keys as well as the value in a collection like a `PriorityQueue` need to use an object contains references to all of those values. While you could try to use generic classes like `Tuple<MyObj, Integer, Double>` in many cases it's best to create a more specific class that makes it easier to understand the individual components, e.g. something like this:

```
class HeapEntry {
  private MyObj x;
  private int i;
  private double value;

  //constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

Then use a `Comparator<HeapEntry>` to go along with a `PriorityQueue<HeapEntry>`:

```
PriorityQueue<HeapEntry> minHeap = new PriorityQueue(Comparator.comparingDouble(HeapEntry::getValue);
```

`Comparator.comparingDouble(HeapEntry::getValue)` is using a method reference and could also be rewritten as `Comparator.comparingDouble(entry -> entry.getValue())`. Before lambdas were available the comparator could have looked like this:

```
//creating an anonymous implementation of Comparator
Comparator<HeapEntry> heapComp = new Comparator<HeapEntry>() {
  public int compare(HeapEntry left, HeapEntry right) {
    //easy to do with primitives
    //if you're using wrapper objects you need to deal with nulls, i.e. decide whether a null value is greater or lower than a non-null value
    return Double.compare(left.getValue(), right.getValue());
  }
};
```

Note: before the edit the code was using `Comparator.comparing(...)` to build the comparator which is fine is the value uses the wrapper type `Double`. However, since the type of `value` is `double`, i.e. the primitive type, we need to use `Comparator.comparingDouble()`.

Comment: Thanks! So I will have an additional class of `HeapEntry`. And an additional class that implements the `Comparator` interface? Or where exactly does the definition of the comparator go in? In the `HeapEntry` class or in a seperate class?

Comment: I implemented a class for the comparator called `MyObjComparator`. I then added:
`MyObjComparator myComp= new MyObjComparator();` and
       `minHeap = new PriorityQueue<HeapEntry>(myComp);`. Is this correct?
Inside  `MyObjComparator` I defined:
`public int compare(HeapEntry v_i, HeapEntry v_j)
        {
            double val1 = v_i.getPathVal();
            double val2 = v_j.getPathVal();
            if(val1 > val2)
                return 1;
            if(val1 < val2)
                return -1;
            return 0;
        }`

Comment: @Eric_ your implementation looks correct albeit it's a little hard to read in a comment given the formatting isn't intended for larger portions of code. However, `Comparator.comparing(HeapEntry::getValue)` would also basically create a similar comparator, or more correctly `Comparator.comparingDouble(HeapEntry::getValue)` (since `comparing()` requires the use of wrapper types.

Comment: OK, , Thanks! :)